# Cannot find module '@google-cloud/logging'

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am new in firebase Functions. In my functions/index.js I defined :

```
const Logging = require('@google-cloud/logging');
```

When I run firebase deploy --debug , I constantly get **error**:

```
 Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module '@google-cloud/logging'
```

Why I get this error???

(BTW, in the `firebase init` , I selected `Functions`:
[image])

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't use a module until you install it into your project and it appears in your package.json.  Run this in your `functions` folder:

```
npm install @google-cloud/logging
```